# Alter a cell's colour based on another cell's value

Tags: google-sheets, gs-conditional-formatting

I have a Google Sheets and need to change the background colour of cells in which values are multiples of another cell's value.

For example, if the range I wanted to check was B2 to K11 and the cell which value I want to check against is F15, how would I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try selecting range B2:K11 and click Format > Conditional formatting > Custom formula is:

`=MOD(B2,$F$15)=0`

Comment: Thanks a lot! That really helped :)